# Using Java Streams to group together a List of objects by an attribute and reduce them to a new list of object with the average of another attribute

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, reduce

I have a list of SensorSample POJOs

```
public class SensorSample {

    private Device.SensorType sensorType; // This is an enum
    private double sample;
    private long timestamp;

    // Constructor

    // Setters

    // Getters

}
```

I need to group them by the `timestamp`, so that all the `SensorSample`s of the same day are together. Then I need to reduce them so that I have only one `SensorSample` for each day and the value of its `sample` is the average of the value of the `sample` of all the objects for that day. Is there a way to do that with Streams?

So far I got this to group them together:

```
Map<Long, List<SensorSample>> yearSamples = samples.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(sample -> SECONDS_IN_A_DAY*Math.floorDiv(sample.getTimestamp(), SECONDS_IN_A_DAY)));
```

But I don't know how to go any further.

Comment: You should use the version of `groupingBy` that has two parameters. The second parameter is your second collector, which does the reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems as if you want a `List<SensorSample>` as a result where each group after the `groupingBy` is reduced into a single `SensorSample`.

```
List<SensorSample> result = samples.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(sample -> SECONDS_IN_A_DAY*Math.floorDiv(sample.getTimestamp(), SECONDS_IN_A_DAY))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> {
                    SensorSample sensorSample = new SensorSample();
                    sensorSample.setTimestamp(e.getKey());
                    double average = e.getValue().stream()
                            .mapToDouble(SensorSample::getSample)
                            .average().orElse(0);
                    sensorSample.setSample(average);
                    sensorSample.setSensorType(e.getValue().get(0).getSensorType());
                    return sensorSample;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `map` logic seems a little bit large thus I'd consider refactoring it out to a method as such:

```
private static SensorSample apply(Map.Entry<Long, List<SensorSample>> e) {
        SensorSample sensorSample = new SensorSample();
        sensorSample.setTimestamp(e.getKey());
        double average = e.getValue().stream()
                .mapToDouble(SensorSample::getSample)
                .average().orElse(0);
        sensorSample.setSample(average);
        sensorSample.setSensorType(e.getValue().get(0).getSensorType());
        return sensorSample;
}
```

Then the stream pipeline would become:

```
List<SensorSample> result = samples.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(sample -> SECONDS_IN_A_DAY*Math.floorDiv(sample.getTimestamp(), SECONDS_IN_A_DAY))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(Main::apply)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where `Main` is the class containing the `apply` method.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves my problem and it's exactly what I was looking for! I'm gonna mark this as the correct answer. However, I would like to point out that I can't use SensorSample::getTimestamp to group the samples because they all have different timestamps. For that purpose, I have to use the lambda function in my question to give the same timestamp to all the samples belonging to a specific day. I know it's just a minor issue that does not really affect the correctness of your answer, but I'd appreciate if you would correct your answer to better match the question.

Comment: @Marcello Sure will do.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, I think.  To find the average number of a group:

```
Map<Long, Double> averages = samples.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(SensorSample::getTimestamp,
   averagingDouble(SensorSample::getSample)));
```

I didn't expand out your formula for the day, I think it's more readable if I just called `getTimestamp` and leave the details out.  Your code might also be more readable if you added a `getDay` method to `SensorSample`.

Also this would be easier to test if you provided an MCVE, as it's a little hard to test the code above with only one partial class to go on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that way I only get the averages of each group of samples. Instead I need a list of new SensorSample objects, each one having the average of a certain day.